# SQL Server dynamic SQL with error of table variable not declared

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to run a dynamic SQL query on SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @tempTBL TABLE(value1 float)

SET @cmd = 'insert into ' + @tempTBL + ' select value from  table11 as  tb1  inner join table2  as tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id where tb1.id2=''active'''

EXEC (@cmd )
```

I get an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@tempTBL".

If I try

```
'insert into  @tempTBL ...'
```

the same error happens.

I do not want to put `"declare @tempTBL"` in the `@cmd` because it will be run inside in a loop.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: you can't use table variables in dynamic queries; change that to temp table, unless complete script including declaration/usage of your table variable resides inside your dynamic query

Comment: You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626292/how-to-use-table-variable-in-a-dynamic-sql-statement) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891932/how-to-insert-into-a-table-variable-with-a-dynamic-query) for solutions

Comment: "run inside in a loop" <-- red flag! Are you sure you need a loop? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @usa - step back for a sec and consider where you are going with this.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Anything a single column table var can do, a subquery can handle...and the dynamic SQL here only appears to be adding complexity, why are you going this route?  As per above comment, saying this will be used in a loop raises so many red flags that you are likely doing something in a very inefficient manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be using dynamic sql here at all.

```
declare @tempTBL table(value1 float)

insert into @tempTBL
select value 
from table11 as tb1  
inner join table2 as tb2 on tb1.id = tb2.id 
where tb1.id2 = 'active'
```